# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable | Keras-Bert

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm building this model:

```
inputs = model.inputs[:2] 
layer_output = model.get_layer('Encoder-12-FeedForward-Norm').output  
input_layer= keras.layers.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,768))(layer_output)
conv_layer= keras.layers.Conv1D(100, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)   
maxpool_layer = keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(conv_layer)
flat_layer= keras.layers.Flatten()(maxpool_layer)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(flat_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(RAdam(learning_rate =LR),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

and I keep getting this error `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable` I know `layer_output` is a tensor and not a layer and Keras works with layers. But I'm finding it difficult to figure out the right thing to do. I have previously build a biLSTM model with similar inputs and it works fine. Can someone point me to something that will help me understand the issue better? I have tried passing the `input_layer` to the `conv_layer` but I get this error `TypeError: Layer conv1d_1 does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask: Tensor("Encoder-12-FeedForward-Add/All:0", shape=(?, 35), dtype=bool)`

Answer (score 2):

```
input_layer= keras.layers.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,768))(layer_output)
```

You're trying to pass an input to an input tensor???

Either you have a tensor: `layer_output`; or you have an input tensor: `Input(shape...)`. There is no point in trying to mix both things.

In your code, everything on the left side are `Tensor`, and that's correct!
Everything in the middle are `Layer`, and all layers are called with the right side, which are `Tensor`.

```
tensor_instance = Layer(...)(tensor_instance)
```

But `Input` is not a layer, `Input` is a tensor. You cannot `Input(...)(tensor_instance)` because `Input` is not a layer.

There is no need to do anything with `layer_output` (tensor). You already have it, so just go ahead:

```
conv_layer_output_tensor = Conv1D(...)(layer_output)
```

---

Suggestion:

```
inputs = model.inputs[:2] #what is this model??
layer_output = model.get_layer('Encoder-12-FeedForward-Norm').output  
    #this may not work 
    #unless this output can be fully gotten with the two inputs you selected 
    #(and there is a chance that Keras code is not prepared for this)

conv_output = keras.layers.Conv1D(100, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
                                  data_format='channels_first')(layer_output)   
maxpool_output = keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(conv_output)
flat_output= keras.layers.Flatten()(maxpool_output)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(flat_output)
another_model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
another_model.compile(RAdam(learning_rate = LR), 
                      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                      metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I now understand that ```Input(shape=...)``` is a tensor and tensors cannot be passed to tensors.  To answer your question ```inputs = model.inputs[:2] #what is this model??``` this is a pretrained model. I want all its layers except for the last two layers. Also, i have modified my code per your suggestion and i now have this error  ```TypeError: Layer conv1d_1 does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask: Tensor("Encoder-6-FeedForward-Add/All:0", shape=(?, 37), dtype=bool)``` which doesn't have a straightforward solution from my search. Any guidance or suggestions?

Comment: Well... I believe the pretrained model has a mask. A `Masking` layer, or a `mask_zeros` parameter in an `Embedding`, something like that. You must find a way to remove this mask from the pretrained model, which is is easy, unless you create the entire model exactly and copy the weights.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will look into how to remove the mask or any other suitable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
output = Lambda(lambda x: x, output_shape=lambda s: s)(output)
```

before `Conv1D` layer.

Comment: Would the ```input_layer``` be added to that line like this ```output = Lambda(lambda x: x, output_shape=lambda s: s)(input_layer)``` and then the ```output``` will be added to the ```conv_layer``` line?  Also can you please explain what the suggested line does. Thanks.