# I keep getting the error TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
global_average_layer = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch_average.shape)
flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()(base_model.layers[-1].output)
dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = "relu")(flatten)
prediction_layer = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = "softmax")(dense1)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

I keep getting TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable at the line `outputs = prediction_layer(x)`. Any clue what I may be doing wrong?

Edit:
Added a few more lines to make it clear what I am doing

```
base_model = keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))
feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)
global_average_layer = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch_average.shape)
flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()(base_model.layers[-1].output)
dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = "relu")(flatten)
prediction_layer = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = "softmax")(dense1)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494717/typeerror-tensor-object-is-not-callable-keras-bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prediction_layer`, as mentioned on line 5, would be the output of the `Dense` layer, and hence be just a `Tensor` and not a layer.
You do not require the flatten layer on `base_model.layers[-1].output`, and can just do it on `x`.

Comment: Then what happens to the `x` on lines 6-8 that I was trying to incorporate into the model. How do I fit that in. Because if I use `prediction_layer` as you say for the output of the `Dense` layer, those never get incorporated into my model

Comment: @user966615 I do not understand the Model's architecture, could you clarify?

Comment: so I am trying to use a DenseNet121 pretrained model to classify a bunch of images. So the above code is me trying to use transfer learning to achieve this. If you look at the Edit, from the line with the `base_model` through `global_average_layer`, I'm just establishing the layers I want to use. From the line with `flatten` through to `outputs` I'm just stacking or creating the model I plan to use for the image classification

Comment: I believe you're going wrong in the flatten layer. You should initialize `x` before getting the output tensor...

Comment: So do the `x`, then `flatten`, then `dense1`, then `prediction_layer`, then use the prediction_layer as output in the model?

Comment: So flatten `x` instead of `base_model.layers[-1].output`